# How to loop through DataAnnotation’s DisplayName in MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I want to access `DataAnnotation`’s  `DisplayName` and similar `GroupName` of a model class then loop through in MVC view. For Example let me say one of my model properties are like this

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name="Home Phone",GroupName="Home")]
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Home Address", GroupName = "Home")]
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Office Phone", GroupName = "Office")]
    public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Office Address", GroupName = "Office")]
    public string OfficeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

How can I loop through the `DisplayName` where similar `GroupName`?

The result should like this,

Home

1. Home Phone
2. Home Address

Office

1. Office Phone
2. Office Address

Comment: You're making life hard for yourself. Why don't you just group them into separate objects such as `OfficeModel` and `HomeModel`? Much cleaner.

Comment: @mattytommo i support what you said, he can better simply make it two objects for better readability and maintainability.

Comment: Here my purpose of usage is different, I want to achieve something like a dropdown list to provide the options to user for column name selection.

Comment: Take a look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649505/whats-displayattribute-groupname-property-used-for

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper class with a function that use expressions to read the DisplayName and GroupName property of the attribute:

```
    public static string GetDisplayName<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression body = GetMemberExpression(expression);
        DisplayNameAttribute attribute = body.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single();
        return attribute.DisplayName;
    }
```

and use that in your razor:

```
<span>@ReflectionHelper.GetDisplayName((Person p) => p.HomePhone)</span>
```

For readability I recommend you prepare a dictionary (or another model) in your controller using this helper based on your Person class and render that dictionary (or other model) in your view instead of using the helper in razor.

Comment: There is already a helper that does just that: `@Html.DisplayNameFor()`

Comment: @Silvex I tried with your code snippet but it just returning `DisplayName` irrespective of `GroupName`. In my case `DisplayName` should lists where `GroupName=Office`. how can i check this condition?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
public List<string> GetDisplayNamesGrouped(Type ClassName, string GroupName)
    {
        List<string> DisplayNameList = new List<string>();
        var properties = ClassName.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var displayAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute;
            string displayName = property.Name;
            if (displayAttribute != null)
            {
                if (displayAttribute.GroupName == GroupName)
                {
                    displayName = displayAttribute.Name;
                    DisplayNameList.Add(displayName);
                }
            }
        }
        return DisplayNameList;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var Home = GetDisplayNamesGrouped(typeof(Person), "Home");
var Office = GetDisplayNamesGrouped(typeof(Person), "Office");
```